# How can I get the selected range from another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, onedrive

In Office.js, there is no way to access other workbooks besides the one the add-in instance is running in. To get around this limitation, I am using the OneDrive API. I can get data from a range in another workbook by making a get request to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/012ZTSSM34N43BDHHXLNEZ4VU6UJG3CETV/
workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A1:B2')
```

However, I'd like to get the selected range rather than a hardcoded address. Is there any way for one instance of an add-in in one workbook to trigger an instance of an add-in in another workbook to get the selected range and return its address? If possible, I could plug the returned address into the get request like...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/012ZTSSM34N43BDHHXLNEZ4VU6UJG3CETV/
workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(selectedRangeAddress)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the two workbooks are open on the same computer, you can have an add-in in one that the user uses to save the data of the selected range in some online location. Then have an add-in in the other workbook that the user uses to fetch the data.